# Dynamic List never Loading - Using parse.com

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, parse-platform

**SEE REVISION AT BOTTOM** This is a fight card, so it has two people fighting one another, a red vs blue. It has to be a dynamic list that is populated information from parse.com. The first Query is `fightOrder`. This is a class on Parse.com that has two `objectId`'s on a row. The `redCorner` and `blueCorner` find this information in my database (also on parse.com) and display the information accordingly. My problem, is my `progressDialog` box appears, and it never goes away. My list is never populated. I tried doing it without the dialog box, and populating my list with ever query and had same results.

**NOTE:** the list is working properly. This is a list I have used successfully before when I would load my information differently. I am just changing the way I load information because I need to have a database of all fighters, and load my fight card from that list.

**NOTE:** `GetCallBack` and `FindCallBack` are asynchronous, that is why this is an odd loop. I have to wait for the `done()`.

Here is the java

```
public class databaseFightCard extends Activity {
int I;
int size;
private HomeListAdapter HomeListAdapter;
private ArrayList<HomeItem> HomeItemList;
private SeparatedListAdapter adapter;

//this int is to test for main and coMain events. If one is TRUE, It will assign the array position to main or coMain.
int main, coMain;
ParseQuery<ParseObject> blueCorner = ParseQuery.getQuery("FightersDB");
ParseQuery<ParseObject> redCorner = ParseQuery.getQuery("FightersDB");

String name1, name2;
List<String> red = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> blue = new ArrayList<String>();
private ListView listView;

ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_list);

   progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading bout...", true);

    initialization();

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            HomeItem homeItem = (HomeItem) adapter.getItem(position);

            AlertDialog.Builder showFighter = new AlertDialog.Builder(databaseFightCard.this, android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Dialog);

            showFighter.setTitle(homeItem.getHomeItemLeft().toString() + " and " + homeItem.getHomeItemRight().toString());
            showFighter.setMessage("166 - 165\nLogan Utah - Richmond Utah");
            showFighter.setPositiveButton("DONE", null);
            showFighter.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
            AlertDialog dialog = showFighter.show();
            TextView messageView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
            messageView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);


            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), homeItem.getHomeItemLeft().toString() + " " + homeItem.getHomeItemRight().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            System.out.println("Selected Item : " + homeItem.getHomeItemID());
        }
    });


    HomeListAdapter = new  HomeListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 0, HomeItemList);


    //find the fight card, and read the ids
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> fightOrder = ParseQuery.getQuery("FightCard");
    fightOrder.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> parseObjects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                size = parseObjects.size();
                int i = 0;


                while (i < size) {
                    if (parseObjects.get(i).getBoolean("main")) {
                        main = i;
                    }

                    if (parseObjects.get(i).getBoolean("coMain")) {
                        coMain = i;
                    }
                    red.add(i, parseObjects.get(i).getString("redCorner"));
                    blue.add(i, parseObjects.get(i).getString("blueCorner"));
                    i++;
                }

                displayRed();


            } else {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

}



private void displayRed() {


    adapter = new SeparatedListAdapter(this);

    //find one fighter at a time. in the done() method, start the second fighter.

        redCorner.getInBackground(red.get(I), new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    HomeItemList = new ArrayList<HomeItem>();
                    HomeItem homeItem = new HomeItem();
                    homeItem.setHomeItemID(I);
                    name1 = parseObject.getString("Name");
                    homeItem.setHomeItemLeft(name1);
                    HomeItemList.add(homeItem);
                    if (HomeListAdapter != null) {
                        if (I == main) {
                            adapter.addSection(" MAIN EVENT ", HomeListAdapter);
                        } else if (I == coMain) {
                            adapter.addSection(" Co-MAIN EVENT ", HomeListAdapter);
                        } else {
                            adapter.addSection(" FIGHT CARD ", HomeListAdapter);
                        }
                    }
                  displayBlue();
                } else {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                I++;
                while (I < size){
                    displayRed();
                }
                if (size == I) {
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }

            }
        });
    }




private void displayBlue() {



    //find the red fighters then call the dismiss();

    blueCorner.getInBackground(blue.get(I), new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                HomeItemList = new ArrayList<HomeItem>();
                HomeItem homeItem = new HomeItem();
                homeItem.setHomeItemID(I);
                name2 = parseObject.getString("Name");
                homeItem.setHomeItemLeft(name2);
                HomeItemList.add(homeItem);
                if (HomeListAdapter != null) {
                    if (I == main) {
                        adapter.addSection(" MAIN EVENT ", HomeListAdapter);
                    } else if (I == coMain) {
                        adapter.addSection(" Co-MAIN EVENT", HomeListAdapter);
                    } else {
                        adapter.addSection(" FIGHT CARD ", HomeListAdapter);
                    }
                }

            } else {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //if it is done running through all the IDS, set the listView, and dismiss the dialog.


            I++;
            while (I < size){
                displayRed();
            }
            if (size == I) {
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);

               progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
}


private void initialization() {
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Listview);
}
```

**LogCat**

> java.lang.RuntimeException: This query has an outstanding network
>   connection. You have to wait until it's done.

That is pointing to this line:

```
   while (I < size){
                    displayRed();
                }
```

**EDIT**

I believe that it is the async tasks that are causing this.

**On a previous build:** I would call for one line item at a time, add it to my list, repeat until finished, then display list.

**On the this build:** I want to call for `redCorner` add it to my list, call `blueCorner` *add it to the same line*, repeat until finished, then display the list. Here is what it would look like (previous build):

[image: fightCard]

---

**Revised** My question is still unanswered. Maybe I need to simplify it. I will have +-20 `objectId's` from one class.  I took out all the code that is irrelevant. Still getting unexpected results with this code.

```
       redCorner.getInBackground(red.get(i), new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {

                    Log.d("NAME " + i, name1 + " ");

                    i++;
                    while (i < size) {
                        redCorner.cancel();
                        displayRed();
                    }
                    if (i == size) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }

                } else {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is yet another case of not understanding the nature of Async coding (I've seen a lot of questions with the same issue).

In your case you are calling the `displayRed()` method that fires off some async code, then returns.

Here's how your code might run:

- First call to `displayRed()` (dr1)

  - (dr1) Async `redCorner.getInBackground(..)` (async1) started
  - (dr1) returns
- .. some time passes ..
- (async1) `getInBackground(..)` call returns with data, runs code block

  - calls `displayBlue()` (db1)

    - (db1) `blueCorner.getInBackground(..)` (async2) started
    - (db1) returns
  - begins the `while` loop

    - calls `displayRed()` (dr2)

      - (dr2) Async `redCorner.getInBackground(..)` (async3) started
      - (dr2) nothing has touched `I` yet, tries to start another async `redCorner.getInBackgroud(..)` (async4)
      - ERROR

You're writing your code as if the async blocks are running sync instead. Keep in mind that `getInBackground` means "make a web call to get this data, and when something happens (error or success) run this block of code I'm giving you, possibly on another thread".

Think about the order you want to achieve things, realise that you're asking it to start a process that takes some time, and adjust your code accordingly.

Comment: Oh, and just a side-note, if that error didn't pop up you would have queued up potentially hundreds of `redCorner.getInBackground()` calls before the first one returns and modifies `I` to cause the `while` loop to exit.

Comment: Right. Did you read my question fully? I state that my problem most likely lies with the fact I'm running two asynchronous tasks. Good answer though

Comment: I should probably rephrase my question; how do I structure my code to accommodate for the async tasks.

Comment: Update your question, at the bottom spell out the sequence of events you would like to occur and I (or someone else) can show you how to do that in an async-safe way.

Comment: Based on your update, it looks like you have the ID for the red/blue FightersDB objects, so you could just change it to load those related objects when you do your `findInBackground` on the FightCard objects. See this link: https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#queries-relational

Comment: That is what I am doing with this code shown. The only change is I try to retrieve the relational objects in two different queries.

Comment: Look at the examples of `include(..)` in the link I gave you, get everything in a single query.

Comment: include wouldnt work in my situation. I need only about 11 of 400 different Id's out of a class.  Unless I could include an array somehow.

Comment: In that case look at `whereContainedIn` at this link https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#queries-constraints

Comment: I am not accepting your answer. But you are getting credit because you mentioned `whereContainedIn`.

Comment: so can we say that his problem was generating race conditions?